# Orion CB Batch updates and notifications throttle

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm running several batch updates (with about 200 entities each one) and I have a Quantum Leap subscribed to the CB to capture the historical data. It is supposed that each batch update should generate 200 different notifications, but, if I have set a throttle of "1", does this mean I will only receive the first notification and loose the other 199? Is this right? (just watching the QL, it seems to me that I'm loosing many notifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities are processed one by one during a batch update request. Thus, if you have 200 entities the update in each one triggers a subscription, then you will have 200 notifications being sent.

The throttling effect depends on the case. For instance:

- If each entity triggers *a different* subscription, then they have any effect (as the trottling is evaluated by subscription)
- If each entity triggers *the same subscription* and assuming that all the 200 notifications are send very fast (let's say, less than 1 second) then only the first one will be sent, and the 199 remaining ones will be lost.

In general, we don't recommend to use throttling due to this (and some other :) problems. It uses to be better to implement traffic flow control in the receiver.

Comment: It looks like the QL subscription method sets throttle to 1 as a minimum (I tried using its API). Should I create the subscrition manually, setting the throttle to '0' so 200 simultaneous updates could be sent to the QL?

Comment: If QL doesn't allow to set the throttling in the subscription it does (that question should be moved to QL developers ;) creating the subscription yourself without including the throttling field in it (throttling: 0 should be equivalent to omitting the field, but I'm not fully sure right now) sounds a good alternative to me.